# Google sheets Sumifs multiple criterias

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I was to calculate the Weekend data from this chart [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA1aV.png), by the following 2 formulas.

**Formula A**

```
=SUMIFS($C2:2,$C$1:$1,{"Fri","Sat","Sun"})
```

Result:

Only the data for Friday.

**Formula B**

```
=SUMIFS($C2:$2,$C$1:$1,"Fri")+SUMIFS($C2:$2,$C$1:$1,"Sat")+SUMIFS($C2:$2,$C$1:$1,"Sun")
```

Result:
Works properly.

**So my question is that**, the formula A works correctly in EXCEL, how should I change and make it work in GOOGLE SHEET as well?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:2, REGEXMATCH(C1:1, "(?:)fri|sat|sun")))
```

[image]

or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:2, REGEXMATCH(C1:1, "(?:)fri|sat|sun"))
```

[image]